# Flutter local notifications, custom sound not working for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, notifications, flutter-dependencies

I am using `flutter_local_notifications: 4.0.1+2` in my project.
Notifications appear I am trying to play custom sound on iOS.'
I tried following to achieve custom sound for iOS but it is not working:

```
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  ?.requestPermissions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
  android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'Adhan Times Notification', 'Islamic App', 'Allah O Akbar',
          priority: Priority.high,
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('azan'));
  const IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      IOSNotificationDetails(sound: 'azan.aiff');
```

`azaan.aiff` file is in `app/ios/Runner`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: also i need solution anyone help me please for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

After days of troubleshooting, I've successfully implemented local notifications in Flutter using the flutter_local_notifications package. Below is a concise guide and warning for others who may face similar challenges.

1. pubspec.yaml:

   ```
    environment:
      sdk: '>=2.19.2 <3.0.0'
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      timezone: ^0.9.2
      flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0+1
   ```
2. notification_service.dart:

   ```
    class LocalNotificationService {
      final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
      final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin = const DarwinInitializationSettings();

      Future<void> showNotification(title, description, route) async {
        // Android Notification Configuration
        AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'jbvfbfdjh', // Customize channel id
          'channel_default', // Customize channel title
          channelDescription: 'channel_default',
          playSound: true,
          sound: const RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification_sound'), // Add your sound file WITHOUT file extension (ex.: .mp3, .mp4, etc)
          importance: Importance.max,
          styleInformation: BigPictureStyleInformation(
            const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('@mipmap/launcher_icon)'),
            largeIcon: const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('@mipmap/launcher_icon'),
            contentTitle: title,
            summaryText: description,
          ),
          enableVibration: true,
        );

        // iOS Notification Configuration
        DarwinNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'notification_sound.caf' // add the sound file name with the extension
        );

        NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
          iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics
        );

        final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
          android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
          iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin
        );

        // Show the notification
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          title,
          description,
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: route,
        );
      }
    }
   ```

**Warning:**

Your notification sound must be placed in two locations for proper functionality on Android and iOS.

For Android, place it at

```
your_flutter_project/android/app/src/main/res/raw/notification_sound.mp3.
```

[image]

For iOS, open ios/Runner.xcworkspace on XCode and place your sound in the root directory.

[image]

Ensure you use the appropriate file extensions for Android (.mp3) and iOS (.caf).

I hope this guide helps others facing similar challenges with local notifications in Flutter. If you have any questions or need further clarification, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `playsound` must be set to true, in addition to the `sound` attribute of the `IOSNotificationDetails` constructor.

Comment: there is not `play sound` attribute. it was `present_sonud`.

Comment: the correct argument name is `presentSound`

Answer (score 0):

```
 const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
    DarwinNotificationDetails(sound: 'slow_spring_board.aiff');

    final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      iOS: darwinNotificationDetails,
      //  linux: linuxPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id++,
      'custom sound notification title',
      'custom sound notification body',
      notificationDetails,
    );
```

also drag and drop sound file in ios folder in xcode

Answer (score -1):

you can call below method in you init method of your home screen

```
 void _requestPermissions() {
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.requestPermissions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.requestPermissions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please read my question again sir i am asking where to put my custom sound for ios local notification. means for android we put custom sound in raw folder.

Comment: @HamadBangash , you must place it in the application bundle (top level directory of your Xcode project) of the client app or in the runner folder of your app.

Comment: manpreet i have updated my question. Have a look